# How does one create a cross tab table?

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to count unique combinations in two Polars columns.

## In R

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2,0,1,0,0,0), b = c(1,1,1,0,0,1))
table(df) 
    0 1
  0 2 2
  1 0 1
  2 0 1
```

## In Pandas

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,0,1,0,0,0])
b = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,1])
pd.crosstab(a, b)
    0   1       
0   2   2
1   0   1
2   0   1
```

## In Polars

Is this the proper way?

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [2,0,1,0,0,0],
        "b": [1,1,1,0,0,1]
    }
)
df.pivot(values="a", index="b", columns="a", aggregate_function="count").fill_null(0)
```

Comment: Internally, pandas' [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) uses a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), so this looks like a good approach.

Comment: It is just the generation of NULLs that is freaking me a bit out. If it is a real crosstab it should count 0 and not NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to invert your "a" and "b" in your pivot. You can also use the `sort_columns` parameter along with a `.sort` at the end to get the same output

```
df.pivot('b', 'a','b','count',sort_columns=True).fill_null(0).sort('a')
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ u32 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: This doesn't really address what was asked, no?

Comment: @mozway how does it not? The question was how to do a thing and this is how to do the thing. Is your point more akin to why doesn't polars have a built in method to do this?

Comment: yes I thought the question was more "*is there a builtin way other than `pivot`?*", not "*how to use `pivot`?*". But glad OP got what they wanted.